# Imagem não está mudando quando clico (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html5, front-end, javascript-eventos, event-listener

Estou fazendo um jogo da velha e adicionei um eventListenner à cada espaço, para que assim que eu clicasse, a imagem mudasse. Porém não está funcionando e não consigo entender o porquê.

Segue o jS,HTML,CSS e as imagens
[image: Circulo]
[image: X]

```js
const player1 ="X";
const player2 ="O";
var playTime = player1;
var gameOver = false;

updateDisplay();
initiateSpaces();


function updateDisplay(){

    if(gameOver){
        return;
    }

    if (playTime == player1)
    {
        var player =document.querySelectorAll("div.display img")[0];
        player.setAttribute("src", "./Assets/images/X.png");

    }
    else{
        var player = document.querySelectorAll("div.display img")[0];
        player.setAttribute("src","Assets/images/circle.png");
    }

}

function initiateSpaces(){
    var spaces = document.getElementsByClassName("space");

//Adicionando um EventListner para cada Espaço
    for (let index = 0; index < spaces.length; index++) {

        spaces[index].addEventListener("click",function(){
            if (gameOver){
                return;
            }
            //Adicionando a condição para o click

            if(this.getElementsByTagName("img").length ==0){
                if(playTime == player1){

                   this.innerHtml = "<img src ='./Assets/images/X.png'>"
                   this.setAttribute("jogada",player1);
                   playTime = player2;

                }
                if(playTime ==player2){
                    this.innerHtml = "<img src ='./Assets/images/circle.png'>"
                    this.setAttribute("jogada",player2);
                    playTime = player1;
                }
                updateDisplay();
            }
        });


        
        
    }



}
```

```css
.game{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.game > .table >.space{

    width: 80px;
    height: 65px;
    border:2px solid black;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}


.table{
    width:calc(84*3px);
}

.display{

    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

.image{
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.game > .table > .a-line{
    border-top: none;
}

.game > .table > .c-line{
    border-bottom:none;
}

.game > .table > .column-1{
    border-left:none;
}

.game > .table > .column-3{
    border-right:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='./Assets/CSS/index.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div class="display">
            <p style="float: left;">Vez do Jogador:  </p>
            <img src="" height="50" >
        </div>
        <div class="table">
            <div id="a1" class="space a-line column-1" jogada="">
                <img src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div id="a2" class="space a-line column-2" jogada="">

            </div>
            <div id="a3" class="space a-line column-3" jogada="">

            </div>
            <div id="b1" class="space b-line column-1" jogada="">

            </div>
            <div id="b2" class="space b-line column-2" jogada ="">

            </div>
            <div id="b3" class="space b-line column-3" jogada ="">

            </div>
            <div id="c1" class="space c-line column-1" jogada ="">

            </div>
            <div id="c2" class="space c-line column-2" jogada ="">

            </div>
            <div id="c3" class="space c-line column-3" jogada ="">

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Assets/JS/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Robert, o erro está principalmente na propriedade innerHtml, na verdade é `innerHTML`, apenas essa questão de case sensitive.

Porém além disso, o seu if de jogador está gerando problemas, pois você troca para o jogador 2 e na sequência verifica se foi ele que jogou, então ali é melhor fazer um `else if`, caso contrário sempre será a vez do primeiro jogador.

*Também mudei o endereço das imagens para as que você anexou, mas pode desconsidera essa parte, deixei assim apenas para ficar visualmente melhor na execução dentro do stackoverflow.*

```js
const player1 ="X";
const player2 ="O";
var playTime = player1;
var gameOver = false;

updateDisplay();
initiateSpaces();


function updateDisplay(){

    if(gameOver){
        return;
    }

    if (playTime == player1)
    {
        var player =document.querySelectorAll("div.display img")[0];
        player.setAttribute("src", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szfrh.png");

    }
    else{
        var player = document.querySelectorAll("div.display img")[0];
        player.setAttribute("src","https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9poD.png");
    }

}

function initiateSpaces(){
    var spaces = document.getElementsByClassName("space");

//Adicionando um EventListner para cada Espaço
    for (let index = 0; index < spaces.length; index++) {

        spaces[index].addEventListener("click",function(){
            if (gameOver){
                return;
            }
            //Adicionando a condição para o click

            if(this.getElementsByTagName("img").length ==0){
                if(playTime == player1){

                   //Corrigi a propriedade aqui
                   this.innerHTML = "<img src ='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szfrh.png'>"
                   this.setAttribute("jogada",player1);
                   playTime = player2;

                }
                //Criei o else if para que seja efetuada a troca de jogadores
                else if(playTime ==player2){
                    //Corrigi a propriedade aqui
                    this.innerHTML = "<img src ='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9poD.png'>"
                    this.setAttribute("jogada",player2);
                    playTime = player1;
                }
                updateDisplay();
            }
        });
        
    }

}
```

```css
.game{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.game > .table >.space{

    width: 80px;
    height: 65px;
    border:2px solid black;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 15px;
}


.table{
    width:calc(84*3px);
}

.display{

    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}

.image{
    margin-right: 200px;
}

.game > .table > .a-line{
    border-top: none;
}

.game > .table > .c-line{
    border-bottom:none;
}

.game > .table > .column-1{
    border-left:none;
}

.game > .table > .column-3{
    border-right:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='./Assets/CSS/index.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div class="display">
            <p style="float: left;">Vez do Jogador:  </p>
            <img src="" height="50" >
        </div>
        <div class="table">
            <div id="a1" class="space a-line column-1" jogada="">

            </div>
            <div id="a2" class="space a-line column-2" jogada="">

            </div>
            <div id="a3" class="space a-line column-3" jogada="">

            </div>
            <div id="b1" class="space b-line column-1" jogada="">

            </div>
            <div id="b2" class="space b-line column-2" jogada ="">

            </div>
            <div id="b3" class="space b-line column-3" jogada ="">

            </div>
            <div id="c1" class="space c-line column-1" jogada ="">

            </div>
            <div id="c2" class="space c-line column-2" jogada ="">

            </div>
            <div id="c3" class="space c-line column-3" jogada ="">

            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Assets/JS/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

> O jogo ainda não tem um algorítimo de vencedor, isso eu não fiz :D